# Symfony Doctrine - request works but "Deprecated Calls"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm kinda new with Symfony and Doctrine. I'm trying to build a function that returns all the "questions" from a "category". I wrote this code that works, but the SF toolbar tells me it's not the right way "**Deprecated Calls**".

Here is my code :

```
public function showAction(Category $category)
{   
    $c_id = $category->getId();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $connection = $em->getConnection();
        $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT id, title FROM question WHERE category_id = $c_id");
        $statement->execute();
        $questions = $statement->fetchAll();

    return $this->render('IelCategoryBundle:Category:show.html.twig', array(
        'category' => $category,
        'questions' => $questions
    ));   
}
```

I'm sure there is a better way to write this, but I'm not comfortable with this doctrine code. Any advice would be really appreciated ! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first in sf 2.3 getEntityManager() is deprecated. You should use getManager() instead.

At second you probably don't want use RAW SQL, see [Doctrine 2 DQL documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)

Comment: It's right for getManager() ! Finaly, I found that the solution was very simple... I just had to use the getter from my Category entity : $questions = $category->getQuestions();